# ECS/nginx/nodejs - How can I serve static files using nginx on a multi-container ecs?

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have a nodejs express app deployed using ecs single container works fine. Now i need to serve the static files of the nodejs app using nginx proxy.
How do I specify the root of the nginx in a multicontainer environment on ECS?

```
upstream cms_node_server_dev {
     server marketing-site-container:3000;
     keepalive 64;
}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    root '/home/ubuntu/cms/dev/static-website/public';

    location /{
        try_files $uri @cms_node_server_dev;
    }
    location @cms_node_server_dev {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass         http://cms_node_server_dev;
    }

    error_page 404 = /404;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you'd have to use shared non-persistent data volume to store common data (static files): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/using_data_volumes.html